# Running busted from luarocks - 'busted' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: lua, luarocks, lua-busted

I just started learning Lua (and am pretty new to programming/command line in general) and I am trying to install busted (a testing framework) from luarocks. When I run "luarocks install busted" it says that it is installed, but when I run "busted," it says it is not recognized as a command. I have tried adding where busted is installed to my Path variable, but so far that has not seemed to work. Currently I'm using Windows.

This is the error I get:

> 'busted' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

Comment: That sounds just like an issue with the path. What is the path that you added and what does `luarocks path --bin` put out?

Comment: I looked at the path and I recognized my mistake, I just needed to set the path correctly. Thank you!